# Do credentials get saved automatically when you do a svn checkout?

Tags: svn

I need to do a svn checkout on a server that's not mine and i just have a quick question.
If i do a:

```
svn checkout https://path.to/svn/trunk/ folder --username myusername
```

Will my username and password be saved so that when i disconnect from that server someone will be able to just do `svn update` or `svn comit` with my credentials?

**LE:**

I'll will connect to a linux server (CentOS - but i don't thinks the distro is relevant) through ssh and i will run those commands from the shell (bash), and then after the checkout and maybe some updates i will disconnect.

Comment: Saved where?  Where is this "someone" doing the update from?

Comment: I think daniels is using someone else's computer to check out a project from svn, and is asking whether the svn client saves the username/password so that whoever owns the computer can use it after daniels leaves.

Comment: @DerfK Ok, I think you're right.  This begs the question then, "Which client?"

Comment: @DerfK Yes, that's correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know specifically about your client, but the svn client in FreeBSD ports takes the option --no-auth-cache to prevent it saving any auth details. Otherwise they're stored in ~/.svn.

Comment: Perfect. Thank you. Well i think tis the same client as i'm am using the standard one http://subversion.tigris.org/

Answer (score 0):

The credentials are not saved on the server and on the client it's client specific, so you'll need to check for the client you're using. If in doubt ask on that client's support forum, help desk or whatever else they might have.